# drop down menu pushing other links down when hovering over

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to create a drop-down menu in CSS.

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #282828;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: left;*/
  color: #abcbe3;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #abcbe3;
}

.navbar ul li ul li {
  display: none;
  background-color: #282828;
}

.navbar ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <!--Dropdown Navigation Bar for Products-->
    <li><a>Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="pages/cpu.html">Processors</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/cpu.html">Graphics Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/cpu.html">Motherboards</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/cpu.html">Power</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="pages/register.php">Login/Reigster</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem which I am having is when I hover over the drop-down menu it pushes the other links down.

I think it has something to do with how I am displaying the elements. However, I need the navigation bar centred in the middle of the .navbar class.

[Here is the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEXtN.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.navbar ul li` display is inline-block, you can add the property `vertical-align: top` to it and it will be fixed.

Something like that maybe?

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #282828;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: left;*/
  color: #abcbe3;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #abcbe3;
}

.navbar ul li ul li {
  display: none;
  background-color: #282828;
}

.navbar ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <!--Dropdown Navigation Bar for Products-->
    <li><a>Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="pages/cpu.html">Processors</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/cpu.html">Graphics Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/cpu.html">Motherboards</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/cpu.html">Power</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="pages/register.php">Login/Reigster</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute` to the `<ul>` that is showing on hover :)
After doing that, this list will not be in the regular page flow and it will not push the rest of the elements down :)

https://jsfiddle.net/f84xwsd5/

Comment: @Phenj is it what you wanted to achieve ?